# Divisible by two given integers

Tags: python, division

```
x=[1,2,3,4,5,6]

for y in x:
    if y %2 == 0:
        print (y)
    elif y %3 == 0:
        print ("y")
    elif y %3 and y %2 ==0:
        print ("Divisible by 2 and 3!")
    else:
        print ("Odd number!")
```

I was trying to find out the even and odd numbers between 1 to 6. All worked out fine except the integer 6 where I need it to print out that the integer 6 is divisible by 2 and 3. How can I fix the error?

Comment: The problem is with ordering of `if` conditionals, swap your second and third `elif` statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test for divisible by 2 and 3 should come first, so for 6 you have `y %3==0 and y %2 ==0` evaluated instead of `y %2 == 0`:

```
for y in x:
    if y % 3 == 0 and y % 2 == 0:
        print ("Divisible by 2 and 3!")
    elif y % 2 == 0:
        print (y)
    elif y % 3 == 0:
        print (y)
    else:
        print ("Odd number!")
```

Comment: Why should it come first? I mean the divisible by 2 and 3?

Comment: So it gets evaluated first and you get the relevant message printed for 6, or else, the branch for %2 will be the executed branch and the others are skipped.

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems here: first of all, the condition should be:

```
elif y %3 == 0 and y %2 ==0:
```

Since there are two **separate conditions**. Next you need to move that check **to the top**, so:

```
for y in x:
    if y %3 == 0 and y %2 ==0:
        print ("Divisible by 2 and 3!")
    elif y %2 == 0:
        print (y)
    elif y %3 == 0:
        print ("y")
    else:
        print ("Odd number!")
```

Why? Because if a number is dividable by 2 and 3, it is also dividable by 2. So that means in your case **it would have picked the first branch**. By swapping the order it will first check if it is dividable by `2` and `3`. If that is not the case - that is if at least one condition fails - it will check the remaining branches.

Comment: @FaisalBuzuobar: Moses was first, so I think it would be correct if he gets the accepted answer :)

Comment: Nice explanations, every time :)

Comment: I'm new here guys. How can i make Moses get the correct answer?

Comment: @FaisalBuzuobar: you just did: click the check mark.